# "Getting Windows ready. Don't turn off your computer": Is there any way to get some estimate as to how long it'll take? (eg, 30 seconds vs 30 minutes)

Tags: windows-10, wait

When Microsoft Windows 10 says:

> Getting Windows ready. Don't turn off your computer.

Is there any way to get some estimate as to how long it'll take? (e.g., 30 seconds vs. 30 minutes)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It depends on:

1. Whether you are keeping Windows up to date. Older versions need fuller Feature updates which take longer. Newer Windows versions take advantage of Windows Enablement to speed up the update process.

[[Windows Enablement[1]](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/feature-update-via-windows-10-version-1909-enablement-package-f23694fa-7088-6d16-2b73-bf7e2ea45cd1)

2. Whether your computer has a slow (5,400 rpm) hard drive or a fast SSD drive.
3. Not so much on CPU speed.

My i7 and i5 are fully up to date, both have fast SSD drives, and they complete this part of updates in about 10 minutes.  The entire update cycle (Don't turn computer off, restart, finish updates) borders on 20 - 30 minutes.

Slower drives or older versions might take an hour or more.